# Disable Excel Macros When Running Directly

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I am facing an error on my current project.

This is the project requirements:

Client has xlsm excel file with macros in it.
Client want that macro will be only available if it opened by my developed App.

So, I have tried this:

a) I password protect the file and open using following code:

```
objEApp = Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"))
objEApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile, password:="excelpassword")
objEApp.Visible = True
objEApp = Nothing
```

b) and put another function and with the help of a third party library, I remove the macros from excel file and save as client version (another file).

but the client is not happy with it as:

1. it creates two excel file one is for the full version password protected, another is for the client version.
2. he also doesn't want the excel file to be password protected.
3. he wants it as very simple

a) if the user opens the excel file directly (double click or open through excel) then VBA macros will not be present/work.

b) if the user opens the excel file by my software then it will work with those macros.

so, I am out of ideas now. I can't figure out how that is even possible?

though, I have an idea.. but can't find the way to achieve it.

for example, I put a global Boolean variable on macro scripts, like bolAppRun Macro with a default value to false.

and when this file is opened via my software, my software just set the Boolean value to true. so, that macro will work. however, when user saves the excel file that Boolean value will not be saved.

something like:

```
objEWorkBook = objEApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile, password:="excelpassword")
objEWorkBook.bolAppRun = true;
```

any idea to achieve my idea.. or do you have a better idea.

thanks in advance
best regards

Comment: Maybe you can move the code to an AddIn, which you keep to yourself?

Comment: @chrisneilsen, sir, thanks for your reply, i have also thought that but is not what client want. because he will work on the master file and edit the code anytime he want. :(

Comment: @chrisneilsen, sir, as i didn't get any answer or any suggestion , can you tell me how i can move all vb codes from excel files to a add-in and run the add-in from my software only? please make sure all moved code should work as it is running from the excel file. .. would you please  help me out?